# Delete unziped files

Tags: php

I have some problem with my script. when I unzip use tis script

```
if (file_exists($zipfile))
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($zipfile) === TRUE)
    {
        if ($zip->extractTo($path) === TRUE)
            return 'file extracted';
        else
            return 'cant extract';
        $zip->close();
    }
    else
    {
        return 'cant open file 2';
    }
}
else
{
    return 'zip doesnt exist';
}
```

I can't delete extracted file use ftp. Folder($path) have chmode 777 but when I try delete extracted file use ftp I see message 
permission denied
But if I upload files to folder use ftp I can delete file

Comment: `$zip->close();` is never called.

Comment: Have you tried to `chmod` the actual file? `chmod($path, 0777)`

Comment: Dahaka is right, the zip is never closed altought could be a permission problem. What chmode has the generated file?

Comment: I try add to scrip this: `$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('./myfolder'), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$fns = array();
foreach($objects as $name => $object)
{
 $fns[] = $object->getPathname();
}
foreach($fns as $fn)
{
echo chown($fn,"username");
}` But I can't change files owner Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

As Dahaka said, `zip-close();` will never be called, as you will either return 'file extracted' or 'cant extract' before reaching the `zip-close();`, thus exiting the method. You should make `zip-close();` come before the returns in your code

Comment: script fixed. But problem not. After unzip use script file owner is www not my login, and file permission 644. And I cant change permission for unzipped file

Answer (score 0):

Very simple but I could be very wrong but I would do `unlink($zipfile);`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you folder has 777 permission the files you extract have the same permission of the user running the server, this is the reason why you can't delete them. You can chmod them to 777 from the PHP after the extraction.